# Copying shape contour adjustments in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Some shapes in powerpoint allow changing the contour using a little yellow handles:

[image]

Sometimes I have another shape of the same cateogry (e.g. another hexagon) that I want to give the same exact contour as the first one. Is there a way to copy-paste these contour modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any direct way of doing this in PowerPoint, but a few lines of VBA will do the job. First, click the shape you want to copy adjustments FROM.  Then hold CTRL and click the shape you want to copy adjustments TO.  Then run the code:

```
Sub CopyAdjustments()

    Dim x As Long

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        For x = 1 To .Adjustments.Count
            ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Adjustments(x) = .Adjustments(x)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

If there are a lot of shapes scattered throughout the presentation that you need to adjust, this will be better. SaveAdjustments saves the adjustments for the currently selected shape to hidden "tags" in the presentation. ApplySavedAdjustments picks up the saved adjustments and applies them to the selected shape.  It's left up to the user to be sensible ... select a shape before picking up/applying adjustments.  And if you save adjustments for one sort of shape and apply them to a different type ... well, best o' luck.

```
Sub SaveAdjustments()

    Dim x As Long

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        If .Adjustments.Count > 0 Then
            ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "Adjustments", CStr(.Adjustments.Count)
            For x = 1 To .Adjustments.Count
                ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "Adj" & CStr(x), CStr(.Adjustments(x))
            Next
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub ApplySavedAdjustments()

    Dim x As Long

    If Len(ActivePresentation.Tags("Adjustments")) > 0 Then
        With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            For x = 1 To CLng(ActivePresentation.Tags("Adjustments"))
                ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Adjustments(x) = _
                CDbl(ActivePresentation.Tags("Adj" & CStr(x)))
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```